# php class method is preventing xml from working correctly

Tags: php, xml, model-view-controller, oop, class

I have a problem that I cannot understand

I am trying to make my webservice work from a class.
I try'd to echo the xml from some function in a controllerclass, but that diddn't work.
So, I moved the xml around to a place where it did work.

That means that I placed it before the loader function is called. That's where it still works. If I place the xml underneath the call to the loader function it's not working anymore.
Thus the loader function somehow is preventing it to work.

I used [this mvc model](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html) as an example how to do it. 
Sofar it all worked, except for the xml implementation now.

This is where it starts

```
<?php
include "registraties/includes/config.php";
include (MYSQL);

//WEBSERVICE SECTIE

/*** include de init.php file ***/
 include 'includes/init.php';

/*** laad de router ***/
$registratie->router = new router($registratie);

/*** set het pad van de controller map ***/
$registratie->router->setPad ('controller');

/*** laad de template ***/
$registratie->template = new template($registratie);
$gebruikersnaam="kabouter";
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$status_code = 2;
        $output= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
        $output.= "<response>\n";
        $output.= "\t<status>$status_code</status>\n";
        $output.= "\t<fout>$gebruikersnaam</fout>\n";
        $output.= "</response>";
        echo trim($output);
        exit();
/*** laad de controller ***/
$registratie->router->loader();
// at this place the xml does not work
?>
```

this is the router class with the loader function in it

```
<?php

class router {
    /*
    * @de registratie
    */
    private $registratie;

    /*
    * @het pad naar de controller map
    */
    private $pad;

    private $args = array();

    public $bestand;

    public $controller;

    public $actie;

    function __construct($registratie) {
        $this->registratie = $registratie;
    }

        /**
    *
    * @set controller directory pad
    *
    * @param string $pad
    *
    * @return void
    *
    */
    function setPad($pad) {

        /*** check of map bestaat***/
        if (is_dir($pad)){
         /*** set het pad ***/
        $this->pad = $pad;
        }else{
                throw new Exception ('Ongeldig controller pad: `' . $pad . '`');
        }      
    }

    /**
    *
    * @laad the controller
    *
    * @access public
    *
    * @return void
    *
    */
    public function loader(){

        /*** check de route ***/
        $this->getController();

        /*** als het bestand niet bestaat ***/
        if (is_readable($this->bestand) == false){

                $this->bestand = $this->pad.'/error404.php';
                $this->controller = 'error404';
        }

        /*** include de controller ***/
        include $this->bestand;

        /*** een nieuwe controller class instance ***/
        $class = $this->controller . 'Controller';
        $controller = new $class($this->registratie);

        /*** check of actie is callable ***/
        if (is_callable(array($controller, $this->actie)) == false){
            $actie = 'index';
        }else{
            $actie = $this->actie;
        }
        /*** voer de actie uit ***/
        $controller->$actie();
    }

    /**
    *
    * @get de controller
    *
    * @access private
    *
    * @return void
    *
    */
    private function getController() {

        /*** get de route van de url ***/
        $route = (empty($_GET['url'])) ? '' : $_GET['url'];

        if (empty($route)){
                $route = 'index';
        }else{
            /*** krijg de segmenten van de route ***/
            $parts = explode('/', $route);
            $this->controller = $parts[0];
            if(isset( $parts[1])){
                $this->actie = $parts[1];
            }
        }

        if (empty($this->controller)){
            $this->controller = 'index';
        }

        /*** get actie ***/
        if (empty($this->actie)){
                $this->actie = 'index';
        }

        /*** set het bestands adres  ***/
        $this->bestand = $this->pad .'/'. $this->controller . 'Controller.php';
    }
}
?>
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: what means "does not work"? any output? have you set display_errors and error_reporting properly?

Comment: I get output in this setup, yes. Below loading(), no
I think the xml just does not arrive.
I have a secondary site to test it on.
I have to see about error reporting, but normally I do see errors, mayby, I don't see them all?

Answer (score 0):

Err - isn't it because of the 'exit()' invocation? I may be wrong.

Comment: thanks, no that has no influence,it's for testingpurposes.
The only thing matters here, is that if I place it under the loader() it doesn't work anymore.